# AngularJS: passing nested angular binding to a controller method

Tags: angularjs

I'm passing a variable to an angular controller function, but as the method has nested bindings the data I pass includes the bindings.

Given the following html:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <div contenteditable 
         ng-model="message.reply.text" 
         ng-focus="expandReply(message.reply)">
        Reply to {{message.Username}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
   $scope.expandReply = function(reply) {
        reply.expand = true;
    }
```

The issue I am trying to overcome is that when I focus on the editable div above the object passed into the above javascript is shown as "Reply to {{@username}}" despite it being correctly displayed. Is there a way to have this show the updated model?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: sorry i paste wrong answer for your question ! i deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was due to non inputs by default not having two binding.

I've implemented a custom directive based on the following:
[angular js two way binding contenteditable via scope attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803171/angular-js-two-way-binding-contenteditable-via-scope-attribute)